# How can I tint an image with react-konva?

Tags: konvajs, react-konva, konvajs-reactjs, konva

I've created a class to load images into my canvas using event listeners, based on the [URLImage example](https://konvajs.org/docs/react/Images.html) on the Konva website.

I have a PNG composed entirely of white pixels on a transparent background. I want to tint the white pixels a solid color (e.g., red, purple, or cyan). I've looked at the [filters example](https://konvajs.org/docs/react/Filters.html), but I'm having trouble understanding how these particular pieces fit together.

How can I do this using react-konva.Image (using, e.g., `<Image filters={[...]} image={...} ref={node => {this.imageNode = node;} />`)?

Here's the TypeScript class I mentioned above:

```js
// import Konva from 'konva';
import React from 'react';
import {Image} from 'react-konva';

type ImgProps = {
    color?: string,
    src: string,
    x?: number,
    y?: number,
};

type ImgState = {
    image: any,
};

class Img extends React.Component<ImgProps, ImgState> {
    private image: HTMLImageElement | undefined;
    // private imageNode: Konva.Image | null = null;

    constructor(props: any) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            image: undefined,
        };
    }

    public componentDidMount = () => {
        this.loadImage();
    }

    public componentDidUpdate = (oldProps: ImgProps) => {
        if (oldProps.src !== this.props.src) {
            this.loadImage();
        }
    }

    public componentWillUnmount = () => {
        if (this.image) {
            this.image.removeEventListener('load', this.handleLoad);
        }
    }

    public render = (): React.ReactNode => {
        return (
            <Image
                image={this.state.image}
                // ref={node => {this.imageNode = node;}}
                x={this.props.x}
                y={this.props.y}
            />
        );
    }

    private loadImage = () => {
        // Save to `this` to remove `load` handler on unmount.
        this.image = new window.Image();
        this.image.src = this.props.src;
        this.image.addEventListener('load', this.handleLoad);
    }

    private handleLoad = () => {
        // After setState react-konva will update canvas and redraw the layer
        // because the `image` property has changed.
        this.setState({
            image: this.image,
        });

        // if (this.imageNode) {
        //     ...
        // }
    };
}

export default Img;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured it out. Using the `Konva.Image` object, which can be set via ref as shown in the question, you must do something like the following:

```js
this.imageNode.cache();
this.imageNode.red(255);
this.imageNode.green(0);
this.imageNode.blue(0);
```

In the class example above, this could be in the `handleLoad` function, or anywhere that has access to this object.

Then render with a `filters` property, like the following example, where `Image` is a `Konva.Image` object:

```js
<Image
    image={this.state.image}
    filters={[Konva.Filters.RGB]}
    ref={node => {this.imageNode = node;}}
/>
```

The [documentation for `Konva.Image.cache()`](https://konvajs.org/api/Konva.Image.html) states (emphasis mine):

> cache node to improve drawing performance, **apply filters**, or create more accurate
>   hit regions. For all basic shapes size of cache canvas will be automatically detected.

The [documentation for inverting an image](https://konvajs.org/docs/filters/Invert.html) states (emphasis mine):

> To apply filter to an `Konva.Image`, we have to cache it **first** with `cache()` function.